# Regular expression in Visual Studio find Replace

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010

Hi I have a html file with hundreds of lines like this

```
<tr>
    <td class="text-column">
        Risk
    </td>
    <td>
        7,848,705
    </td>
    <td>
        7,828,750
    </td>
    <td>
        19,955
    </td>
</tr>
```

To save time formatting it, does anyone know the visual studio find/ replace regular expression that will produce

```
<tr>
    <td class="text-column">Risk</td>
    <td>7,848,705</td>
    <td>7,828,750</td>
    <td>19,955</td>
</tr>
```

I plan to fill in the figures with razor later and this will ease readability.

Answer (score 2):

```
Find: {\<[^\>]+\>}[:b\n]*{[^\n]*}[:b\n]*{\</[^\>]+\>}
Replace: \1\2\3

Explanation:
{\<[^\>]+\>}   -- capture open tag
[:b\n]*        -- discard whitespace
{[^\n]*}       -- get contents (assuming no line breaks)
[:b\n]*        -- discard whitespace
{\</[^\>]+\>}  -- capture closing tag
```

Not perfect, but it produces the expected output on your sample.

Comment: Hey Devon, thanks for this.Tried it in the "Find what" textbox with "use regular expressions" selected, but VS complained with "specified text was not found". Am I doing something wrong? Don't mind doing multiple find replaces.

Comment: Just checking: you have the "Use Regular Expressions" box checked right? Are you using the standard VS Find/Replace dialog or the power tools one?

Comment: The Visual Studio Quick Replace (ctrl +h). Use regular expressions is ticked/selected

Comment: Huh. Not sure why it didn't work. Glad you got something figured out though.

Answer (score 0):

Did it with code in the end. But thanks to Devon for taking the time